# Netmask returned in rt_msghdr2 in invalid format

Tags: ios, c, macos, sysctl

I want to parse the routes returned by the kernel when invoking the `sysctl` function with the arguments: `{ CTL_NET, PF_ROUTE, 0, AF_INET, NET_RT_DUMP2, 0 }`.

After doing that I get several routing messages, in all of them I have found the issue: the `struct sockaddr*` at index `RTAX_NETMASK` doesn't contain a valid `struct sockaddr`.

The code to extract the addresses from the `struct rt_msghdr2` returned by `sysctl` is the following:

```
// ROUNDUP Taken from route.c
#define ROUNDUP(a) \
   ((a) > 0 ? (1 + (((a) - 1) | (sizeof(uint32_t) - 1))) : sizeof(uint32_t))

struct rt_msghdr2* routeMsg = (struct rt_msgdr2*)buffer;
struct sockaddr* sockAddrArray[RTAX_MAX];
memset(sockAddrArray, 0, sizeof(sockAddrArray));
struct sockaddr* currentSockAddr;
currentSockAddr = (struct sockaddr*)(routeMsg + 1);

for (int i = 0; i < RTAX_MAX; i++) {
    if (routeMsg->rtm_addrs & (1 << i)) {
        sockAddrArray[i] = currentSockAddr;
        currentSockAddr = (struct sockaddr *)(ROUNDUP(currentSockAddr->sa_len) + (char *)currentSockAddr);
    } 
    else {
        sockAddrArray[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Even though the `routeMsg` states that it has a netmask, when I check the contents I find that it has something like this:

```
sockAddrArray[RTAX_NETMASK]->sa_len = 0
sockAddrArray[RTAX_NETMASK]->sa_type = \xff
sockAddrArray[RTAX_NETMASK]->sa_data = { \xff, \xff, \0, ...}
```

The weird thing is that the matching route on the host (based on the network and gateway addresses) has the netmask `255.255.255.0` which matches too well to the direct content of the of the netmask `sockaddr`.

Of course, I cannot trust anything else that comes after the `RTAX_NETMASK` in the array as it will be incorrectly parsed.

Does someone know why this happens?